# Detect if the app was launched/opened from a push notification and then redirect it to particular view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, notifications, push-notification

What I am doing is when push notification received I am navigating to particular view controller depending on user info I get from that notification. This navigation and user info is received from method

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

This is working perfectly fine when app is in background and receive notification.
But when my app is force stopped then I get notification and after click on that my app launches first time so then `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is not getting called and I am not able to redirect my app to particular view controller . It just opening first page of my app.
How can i detect that my app is launch from push notification and get info from that notification same which i get from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and now I need to redirect it to particular page? My app support is from iOS 7 and above.
Whats up is doing this type of senario , but can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the notificatin from **didFinishLaunchwithOptions:(lauchoptions)** method. 
In this method, use lauchoptions to read the notification dictionary like
`
if (launchOptions) { //launchOptions is not nil

```
    userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

}`
```

and then set your window.rootviewcontroller based on notification key.